# Do I need an Azure AD app to embed my Power BI reports in my own app?

Tags: reactjs, azure, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I'm confused about the guideline I have to follow to embed some Power BI reports in a react app. I've been reading [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-sample-for-customers?tabs=node-js) documentation but I don't understand why I need an Azure AD app. By now I've created four Power BI reports and I've published them to the web (making them public and accessible for everyone). So, **I've got four PBI links to access them. But I want to create a web app (probably with React) to embed them all in one link.**

I understand that Azure covers authentication features, but my app will only show information, doesn't need users to log in or something. So, I guess Azure helps to authenticate to the PBI account I'm using. But if this is the case, why PBI doesn't ask me for authentication when I share the reports links with anyone?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need Azure AD app to have identity for your application, to authenticate to Azure AD (using MSAL for example) and for using the Power BI REST APIs. Check the following article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/register-app

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already logged in you don't  need to login to PowerBi again, There are two ways to embed your PowerBI reports,

1. Publish to web -> Does not require authentication (Public reports)
2. Embed with authentication -> Hyperlink and token based ( Requires Azure AD)

You can check more information [here](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/demo/v2-demo/index.html)